# Significant Figures for Exponents and Logs

Tags: significant-figures

What are the Sig Fig rules for exponents and logs. Ex. if I have 10^-3.83, or log(4.32) how should the answer be represented

Comment: In wiki, look up “Propagation of uncertainty” and, for a simpler treatment, “Significant figures”. The trouble with significant figures is that they are attempts to express, in *one number*, both a best estimate and an uncertainty. This cannot be perfect, but the rules work reasonably well.

Comment: You asked about the significant figures in $10^{-3.83}$. The digits in the characteristic don't count, but the digits in the mantissa do. Thus there are only 2 significant figures in $10^{-3.83}$.

Comment: The 'rule of thumb' is that the log of the number should have as many digits to the right of the decimal as there are significant digits in the number, e.g. $\log_{10}(0.000012345)=-4.90850$

Answer (score 1):

> if I have 10^-3.83

-3.83 is less than -3.82 and more than -3.84. If we raise 10 to those powers, we get:

$$10^{-3.82} = 0.000151$$
$$10^{-3.84} = 0.000144$$

So the answer is 0.00015 or $\pu{1.5e-4}$

> if I have [...] log(4.32)

$$\log(4.31) = 0.6344$$
$$\log(4.33) = 0.6364$$

So the answer is 0.64.

> What are the Sig Fig rules for exponents and logs?

Once you use exponents and logs a lot, you might also know some calculus to support a better model of error propagation. If not, the rule for logs is that the error is equal to the error of the argument divided by the argument. The rule for exponentials is that the error is equal to the error of the exponent times the value of the exponential. Very few introductory textbooks bother to state these, though.